# Windows Powershell. How to find drives with certain capacity and rename them with PowerShell only?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm very unfamiliar with PowerShell and Windows Scripting. I would need to find 2 hard drives that have a certain, defined capacity such as 300GB. I would then need to rename these hard drives to H: and J: (or ensure their current name is already that).

I'm really not certain how to do this, so I don't have anything to share about things I've tried. Could someone help me out? Thank you very much.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: *"I'm really not certain how to do this"* - Perhaps try [Get-WmiObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) for the current sizes and names of the drives (with `Win32_LogicalDisk`, as outlined [here](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/01/26/view-drive-information-with-powershell.aspx?m=1))... (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Then use [Get-Partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-partition?view=windowsserver2019-ps) and [Set-Partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-partition?view=windowsserver2019-ps) to change the drive letters (as outlined [here](https://winbuzzer.com/2020/08/12/how-to-assign-change-drive-letter-in-windows-10-xcxwbt/)).